# Alphadin BibTeX: DOI displayed twice

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, doi

I'm not quite sure how to explain my problem. Please telle if you need more information. My document is very large and has a lot of settings. I'm using TeXnicCenter with the BibTex-Compiler 2.8. When I'm constructing the PDF (LaTeX->DviPS->PS2PDF), I'm getting this:

[image]

The BibTex-entry:

```
@incollection{Agrawal.2008,
 author = {Agrawal, Motilal and Konolige, Kurt and Blas, Morten Rufus},
 title = {{C}en{S}ur{E}: {C}enter {S}urround {E}xtremas for {R}ealtime {F}eature {D}etection and {M}atching},
 pages = {102--115},
 volume = {5305},
 publisher = {Springer},
 isbn = {978-3-540-88692-1},
 series = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
 editor = {Forsyth, David and Torr, Philip and Zisserman, Andrew},
 booktitle = {{C}omputer {V}ision -- {E}{C}{C}{V} 2008},
 year = {2008},
 address = {Berlin und Heidelberg},
 doi = {10.1007/978-3-540-88693-8\_8}
}
```

What's my problem? The DOI is displayed twice. And I only want the last notation (DOI.10.1007 ...). I've tried the doi-package but this causes a lot of trouble with my tex-files. Could you please help me? I will try to give further informations.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[komastyle,automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,includeheadfoot,width=16cm]{geometry}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin2}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\begin{document}

\chapter{TEST}
This is a test \cite{Agrawal.2008}.

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bib}
\bibliography{minimalbib} %Add the entry i this file
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. Do you use `biblatex`? Your question is tagged with it but `alphadin` doesn't work with `biblatex`.

Comment: I'm not using biblatex. Sorry. I've added a minimal example.

Comment: `alphadin2.bst` isn't available at CTAN. Where does the file come from? Is it equal to `alphadin.bst`?

Comment: I found the the answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de&fromgroups=#!topic/de.comp.text.tex/T9_tIvecoW0 (German). However it's a bug of `alphadin`. You have to change a lot in `alphadin.bst`. Maybe `biblatex` is an option for you.

Comment: Please post your last comment as an answer so that I can accept it. It's no solution but it still helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is a bug of `alphadin.bst`. In a former question at comp.tex.tex [DOI in alphadin](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de&fromgroups=#!topic/de.comp.text.tex/T9_tIvecoW0) (German) the method solving the issue is shown. However every entry type must be redefined.

In my opinion the package `biblatex` is an very good alternative.